# Target Post Type from array Query

Tags: post-type

I have the following query to extract posts from two different types. However, how can I then target them in the actual content display conditional code?

The if ($my_query->post_type == 'featured' ) does not work.  I also tried if (post_type == 'featured' ).

```
    <?php 
// query posts
$my_query = new WP_Query
        ( array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type'   => array('featured', 'wpsc-product'),
        'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        'showposts'   => 50 )); 

while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
$fitemlink = get_post_meta($post->ID,'new_fitemlink',true); 


// display the content 

if ($my_query->post_type == 'featured' ) { 
echo get_image_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slideimage_src', true));

} else if ($my_query->post_type == 'wpsc-product' ) { 
echo wpsc_the_product_image(); } 

endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Try `$post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );` I'm wondering if inside the custom loop `$post->ID` is messed up somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this with a simple query instead

```
if ( 'featured' == get_post_type() )  { echo get_image_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'snbf_slideimage_src', true)); } else if ( 'wpsc-product' == get_post_type() ) { echo wpsc_the_product_image();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$my_query->post_type` refers to the post type of the *query* (in this case an array), and *not* the results. (Its recommended to use `$my_query->get('post_type')` too, but anyway...).

To get the current post's (in the loop) post type:

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
```

You can also use that function outside the loop by passing the post object / ID. See [codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my question but this is not working and nothing shows.  Any Further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the `post_type` property of the query, when in fact you ought to instead ask for that property from the current post variable `$post`.  In fact, [this is exactly what `get_post_type()` does](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1129).

Alternatively, if your query specifies the post type, you might [ask for the corresponding query_var](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrieve-post_type-querystring-value#post-2277860) (e.g. `get_query_var("post_type");`).